# PHP: No output from $row variable even if it is already defined

Tags: php, sql

I don't know why it doesn't show up anything, I already tested my query and it is working in my phpmyadmin, but in my php code it does not work upon adding the AS keyword. My goal for this is to place a value to a variable coming from the SUM() keyword.

```
<?php 
require_once "user-connect.php";
$user = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT SUM(total) AS sumz FROM cart WHERE userID = $user AND month(orderDate) = month(now()) AND day(orderDate) = day(now())";
$result = $link->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['sumz'];
}  
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($link);
} ?>
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th>Cart Subtotal</th>
            <td><span class="amount"><?php echo $row['sumz']; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Does the query fetch any value?

Comment: Are you sure that `$user` is a number? Maybe output its value to be sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(total) FROM cart WHERE..."
```

And in HTML:

```
<td><span class="amount"><?php echo $row['SUM(total)']; ?></span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  [PHP fetch assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) guide.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['sumz'];
}
```

An example of getting the `SUM` value

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT sum(amount) as total FROM table"; 
$result = mysqli_query($sql); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo $row['total']; 
} 
mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```